# How can I fix Error with SelectionDividerHeight?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, custom-renderer

Please help me with this error
[image: Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError Сообщение = no non-static method "Landroid/widget/NumberPicker;.setSelectionDividerHeight(I)V"]

Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'no non-static method "Landroid/widget/NumberPicker;.setSelectionDividerHeight(I)V"'

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: I added as text

Comment: that method was added in API 29.  Which version are you using?

Comment: I use API  29 so I do not understand why I have it

Answer (score 0):

According to the image, it seems like you are using a NumberPicker in Xamarin.Native Android, so it is an easy solution:

```
picker.ShowDividers = ShowDividers.None;
```

Comment: yes.I use NumberPicker,but picker.ShowDividers = ShowDividers.None;  did not help me

Comment: Please share the code of the CustomPicker that is overriding the behavior. It's probably in your adapter